# finding a string in a .txt file -- not having success

Tags: bash

I am trying to grep a line of information from a large .txt file and I've run into a problem where the .txt file seems to be printing out all of the subjects in the .txt file.

I tried:

`grep ""HCA66666""01/01/1900""400"" imagingcollection01.txt`

Then when that wasn't working I backtracked and tried to grep just the subject name:

`grep ""HCA66666"`

with the same outcome.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59201557/edit) to include a sample of what the file you're `grep`-ing looks like. This will make it easier for us to suggest ways to get what you want.

Comment: You cannot use double quotes in double quotes like that. Try `grep "\"HCA66666" Makefile`

Comment: This may work: `grep "HCA66666.*01/01/1900.*400" imagingcollection01.txt`. If  pattern contains a double quotes you could surround it in single quotes like: `grep '"string"'`

Comment: To expand on that: when you type `""HCA66666""01/01/1900""400""`, the shell turns it into `HCA6666601/01/1900400` before grep gets to see it.